# How to check if a tree is a BST?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have to check if a tree is a binary search tree. I'm doing this with an inorder traversal with a temporary array that collects the values. I have to check if the array is ascending order and if it is then I return true:

```c++
bool myisBST(Node* node, std::vector<int> v);

bool myisBST(Node* node)
{
    return myisBST(node, std::vector<int>());
}

bool myisBST(Node* node, std::vector<int> v)
{
    if (node)
    {
        if (node->left)
            return myisBST(node->left, v);

        v.push_back(node->data);

        if (node->right)
            return myisBST(node->right, v);
    }

    return std::is_sorted(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

When binary tree is this:

```c++
            50
           /  \
         25    75
        /  \   / \
       1   12 62 -99
```

As you can see, the `-99` makes this not a binary search tree, but it is still returning true. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17cb6b285c479136)</kbd>

Comment: `-99` makes it not a binary search tree, but it is still returning true. Is there something wrong with your implementation? Do you have a better candidate for something that could be wrong?

Comment: @juanchopanza Come again?

Comment: run your program in debugger and see what execution path it takes. Your code never hits is_sorted check

Comment: You are asking whether there is something wrong with your implementation. I am asking whether that isn't blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. In `myisBST`, you are passing `v` by *value*, not by reference, so when you pass the vector on recursively, the changes that are made to it don't change its value in the calling method. Simply change the function signature to `bool myisBST(Node* node, std::vector<int>& v)` to fix this.
2. The value you should be returning is whether the vector is sorted (as you do in the last line of your method), but instead you are returning prematurely by writing `return myisBST(node->left, v);` and `return myisBST(node->right, v);`. You're not actually interested in the return values of these methods; you're just using them to fill the vector inorder. Remove the `return` from both of these lines.

Following these two fixes, your method works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should probably pass the `vector` by reference or each recursive call will get a copy and thus the original vector will probably be empty.

Second, you don't even need to create the vector first and then do the check, you can just check the BST property at each node, i.e., the root must be bigger than the left child and smaller than the right child, e.g.,

```
bool isBST(const Node* root, vector<int>* v) {
  if (!root) { return true; }

  bool leftBST = true;

  if (root->left) {
    if (root->data > root->left->data) {
      leftBST = isBST(root->left, v);
    } else {
      // the current node violates the BST precondition
      return false;
    }
  }

  // push the root
  v->push_back(root->data);
  // return false if left subtree is not a BST
  if (!leftBST) return false;

  if (root->right) {
    if (root->data < root->right->data) {
      // return whether or not the right subtree is a BST
      return isBST(root->left, v);
    } else {
      // the current node violates the BST precondition
      return false;
    }
  }

  // everything good, this is a BST
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ Program to check if tree is BST or not

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left, *right;
};

bool IsBST(Node* ObjNode)
{
    bool leftBST = false;

    bool rightBST = false;

    if( ObjNode->left != null && ObjNode-left < objNode->data)
    {
        leftBST = IsBST(ObjNode->left)
    }
    else if( ObjNode->left == null)
    {
        leftBST = true;
    }

    else if( ObjNode->left != null  && ObjNode-left >= objNode->data)
    {
        leftBST = false;
    }


    if( ObjNode->left != null && ObjNode-left < objNode->data)
    {
        rightBST = IsBST(ObjNode->right)
    }
    else if( ObjNode->right == null)
    {
        rightBST = true;
    }

    else if( ObjNode->right != null  && ObjNode-right >= objNode->data)
    {
        rightBST = false;
    }


    return (leftBST && rightBST );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the previous solution, they are keeping a list of the inorder traversal, you really don't need it, you can keep checking with the last traversed element and keep moving forward.

> Following solution is the [fastest](https://leetcode.com/problems/validate-binary-search-tree/)

[image]

```
class Solution {
    int lastval = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int count = 0;
    public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return true;
        boolean left = isValidBST(root.left);
        if(!left){
            return false;
        }
        int rootVal = root.val;
        if(rootVal == -2147483648 && count == 0 ){
            rootVal = rootVal + 1;
        }
        if( rootVal <= lastval){
           return false; 
        }
        count ++;
        lastval = root.val;
        boolean right = isValidBST(root.right);
        if(!right){
            return false;
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```